We adopted a rescue dog that we are pretty sure was abused. After about a week hes started peeing on my daughter
He doesn't seem afraid of females or kids. About a week after we got him he started walking up to my adult daughter and lifting his leg and peeing on her. He doesn't seem afraid of her so I wonder if he thinks he's marking his territory? I don't know how to make him stop doing this and my daughter is starting to want to take him back to the shelter. I don't want to so I need to get him to stop doing this.Any suggestions would be welcome!

Whether or not he was abused has nothing to do with his urinating on people. This is just unacceptable behavior, but it seems like he hasn't learned that.
Your daughter is the one who can stop him most effectively, because she is right there when it happens. By now she probably has a hunch for when it happens. When she notices your dog walking up to her to pee, she has to look him in the eyes and say "No!" in an assertive or angry tone. She can even stretch her leg out to physically block his path to her or she can send him out to pee in an appropriate spot. If the dog ignores her and sidles up to her to pee, she can physically push him away by his shoulder. This push shouldn't be painful, it's nonverbal communication for "get away from me" and you can add a verbal scolding to it.
What's important here is that your daughter (or anyone else doing this) stays calm. If you move or speak hectically, the dog thinks you are insecure and have no power to make him do anything. If you stay calm and move just as much as neccessary to get your point across, the dog thinks you know exactly what you want and you'll make it happen. He's much more likely to follow your lead when you are calm and assertive.
